# Forcing text entry on textbox to be am/pm

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I'd like to create a textbox that forces the user to enter either "am" or "pm" or if they don't finish and move to another control having only entered an "a" or "p" automatically finish it off. Or maybe as soon as the user enters "a" or "p" it adds in the "m".

I was thinking of using a regular expression to match the entry somehow. I already have a custom textbox that can check a regular expression, however I am unsure how to construct it.

```
RegularExpression="([AaPp][Mm])"
```

Could some help me with the expression please?

Comment: Why don't you use a select list or radio buttons?

Comment: Thanks and fair enough, but it's not appropriate in this case, it's for a DateTime picker.

Comment: how about formating the textbox to dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt so when they user select from date picker AM PM will be generated and bind the textbox with a datetime properties to ensure they user always enter a valid datetime value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check a whole string, you need to be sure that it matches the pattern from begining to end. This is the reason why you need to use anchors. Without anchors your pattern could match something like `abcdPMefgh`:

```
@"\A[AaPp][Mm]\z"
```

`\A` means *start of the string*

`\z` means *end of the string*

Note that capturing parenthesis are useless since the result you want is the whole match.

If you only need to extract the substring "am" or "pm" from a larger string, `@"\b[AaPp][Mm]\b"` is more appropriate.

An other thing, you can use the regex options to make the pattern case insensitive and simply write `@"\b[ap]m\b"`

Comment: Interesting, in this case the textbox will only have to match on am or pm. So does that mean that \A should always preceed [] and \z always follow []?

Comment: So when I first enter lets say "a" and my match check occurs on each key press, it only has one character, does it not try to match gainst both the start and end rules giving a false result?

Comment: @Hank: if you want to check the validity of a whole string you need to use `\A` at the begining and `\z` at the end. When you enter the first character the pattern doesn't match the string.